# Conditional Page Caching [Solution: Conditional Fragment Caching]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Suppose that I have controller `home_controller.rb` with action `index`.

I want to cache index page so I'm doing:

```
caches_page :index
```

but want it to cache only for users that are not signed in. If I'll make conditional like:

```
caches_page :index, :if => :user_not_signed_in?
```

Page will be cached while first not logged in user comes. Now every logged in user also see not-logged in content. Is there a way to separate this action without changing url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[cache_if](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper/cache_if) and [cache_unless](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper/cache_unless) seems to be the correct way to do this now:

```
cache_if(condition, name = {}, options = nil, &block)
cache_unless(condition, name = {}, options = nil, &block)
```

Your code:

`<% cache_unless @user.changed?, [ @user, 'form' ] do %>`

Answer (score 6):

What you want couldn't be achieved;

A page is cached or is not cached. The process checks the existence of a html file or process it.

Still you have two alternatives:

- use action caching or fragment caching (not recommended)
- more recommended: load user specific part with ajax so you'll only have one page always cached and specific data inserted dynamically (like stackoverflow)

Here are state of the art explanations: http://railslab.newrelic.com/scaling-rails

Comment: Just be kind to users which don't trust JavaScript ;-)

Comment: Ah! You mean 19th century users? Well you're right this category is a pain.

Comment: yep, js may be the solution. But I'll wait for other answers for a little time :)

Comment: it's not the only solution I suggest: action and fragment caching work fine in your situation

Comment: Ok I'm accepting this answer. Meantime i created a gem to satisfy conditional caching https://github.com/dfens/active_cache  , this is still still under heavy maintenance, but may be a solution

Comment: well cached or not… talking about format (like html or json), the output won't be the same most of the time. 2014, not relevant to use cache_page anymore, but everyone would admit it can't be faster/safe with this modern doll thing

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is now out of date, as conditional caching is now available in Rails 4. A [pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5396) was [merged into 4.0.0rc1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6ed4ad133486f235fcba136d3a660d89f769beb9) that allows for `:if` and `:unless` parameters to be passed to `cache`. This allows templates to be DRY, since there is no longer a need to duplicate the conditionally cached block.

Usage:

```
<% cache [ @user, 'form' ], :unless => @user.changed? do %>
  <%= render partial: 'shared/error_messages', locals: {instance: @user} %>
  <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <div><%= f.label :name %></div>
      <div><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me with `<% cache [@questions, @votes], :if => 1==0 do %>` in rails 4.2